# How to calculate each object in the array in separate array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this array

```
bidsList = [
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:5,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      awardedCapacity:10,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:5,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:3,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      awardedCapacity:5,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'C',
      awardedCapacity:2,
    },
```

i need to have separete array where when i make the iteration throught this array i will calculate the total of all awardedCapacities where the supplier name is same

For example i should have array where i will have this output

```
 let newArr = [
    {
      supplierName: 'A',
      totalAwarded: 13,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      totalAwarded: 15,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'C',
      totalAwarded: 2,
    }
  ]
```

because on previous array i had `three`  objects where the supplierName was `A` and when i sum their awarded capacities i am geetting 13 in the other object with it's supplier name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like the following way:

```js
let bidsList = [
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:5,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      awardedCapacity:10,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:5,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:3,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      awardedCapacity:5,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'C',
      awardedCapacity:2,
    }
  ];
  
let newArr = [];
bidsList.reduce(function(acc, val) {
  if (!acc[val.supplierName]) {
    acc[val.supplierName] = { supplierName: val.supplierName, awardedCapacity: 0 };
    newArr.push(acc[val.supplierName])
  }
  acc[val.supplierName].awardedCapacity += val.awardedCapacity;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: thank you. Btw how can be this solved with for loop ?

Comment: @Mamum can you take a look please at my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70080974/how-to-calculate-each-object-in-the-array-in-separate-array-based-on-truthy-cond

Answer (score 2):

[Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
    const newArr = bidsList.reduce((a, o) =>  {  
      const index  = a.findIndex(x => x.supplierName === o.supplierName);
      const s = a[index > -1 ? index: a.push({supplierName:o.supplierName, awardedCapacity:0}) - 1];
      s.awardedCapacity += o.awardedCapacity;
      return a;
    }, [])
```

Comment: @Hary https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70080974/how-to-calculate-each-object-in-the-array-in-separate-array-based-on-truthy-cond

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method

```js
var bidsList = [
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:5,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      awardedCapacity:10,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:5,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:3,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      awardedCapacity:5,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'C',
      awardedCapacity:2,
    }];

var result = bidsList.reduce((a, c) => {

  let supplier = a.find(e => e.supplierName == c.supplierName);
  if (supplier)
    supplier.totalAwarded += c.awardedCapacity;
  else 
    a.push({
      supplierName: c.supplierName,
      totalAwarded: c.awardedCapacity
    });
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you take al ook at my other question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70080974/how-to-calculate-each-object-in-the-array-in-separate-array-based-on-truthy-cond