# How to calculate each object in the array in separate array based on truthy condition?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this array

```
bidsList = [
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:5,
      switcherStatus: true
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      awardedCapacity:10,
      switcherStatus: true,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:5,
      switcherStatus: false,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'A',
      awardedCapacity:3,
      switcherStatus: true,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      awardedCapacity:5,
      switcherStatus: true,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'C',
      awardedCapacity:2,
      switcherStatus: false,
    },
```

i needed to have separete array where when i make the iteration throught this array i will calculate the total of all awardedCapacities where the supplier name is same

For example i should have array where i will have this output

```
 let newArr = [
    {
      supplierName: 'A',
      totalAwarded: 13,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      totalAwarded: 15,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'C',
      totalAwarded: 2,
    }
  ]
```

The solution for this is:

```
let newArr = [];
bidsList.reduce(function(acc, val) {
  if (!acc[val.supplierName]) {
    acc[val.supplierName] = { supplierName: val.supplierName, awardedCapacity: 0 };
    newArr.push(acc[val.supplierName])
  }
  acc[val.supplierName].awardedCapacity += val.awardedCapacity;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newArr);
```

but now i need to check also if the switcherStatus is setted to true only - if it is setted to false i should not calculate it's awardedCapacity and i should not push into the array if it is the only one object

so the output should be

```
 let newArr = [
    {
      supplierName: 'A',
      totalAwarded: 8,
    },
    {
      supplierName:'B',
      totalAwarded: 15,
    },
  ]
```

`C` IS excluded here because it is switcherStatus false, and A is 8 - because on object was with switcherStatus of false

i can't find a way to modify this reduce code here for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a condition in your `reduce` function

```js
var bidsList = [{
    supplierName: 'A',
    awardedCapacity: 5,
    switcherStatus: true
  },
  {
    supplierName: 'B',
    awardedCapacity: 10,
    switcherStatus: true,
  },
  {
    supplierName: 'A',
    awardedCapacity: 5,
    switcherStatus: false,
  },
  {
    supplierName: 'A',
    awardedCapacity: 3,
    switcherStatus: true,
  },
  {
    supplierName: 'B',
    awardedCapacity: 5,
    switcherStatus: true,
  },
  {
    supplierName: 'C',
    awardedCapacity: 2,
    switcherStatus: false,
  }
];

var result = bidsList.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (c.switcherStatus) {
    let supplier = a.find(e => e.supplierName == c.supplierName);
    if (supplier)
      supplier.totalAwarded += c.awardedCapacity;
    else
      a.push({
        supplierName: c.supplierName,
        totalAwarded: c.awardedCapacity
      });
  }
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```